# Fixed Vertical Logo in Sidebar Navigation in Responsive Bootsrap

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, fluid-layout

Is there a way to get the same results with a vertical logo as is achieved with an unordered in the code from: http://jsfiddle.net/ukMqq/94/

I removed the unordered list and inserted an image and it doesn't work. The image only shows up in mobile screen size at the top.

```
CSS

body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

.sidebar-nav-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:60px;
    width:21.97%;
    z-index:-1;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .sidebar-nav-fixed {
        position:static;
        width:auto;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .sidebar-nav-fixed {
        top:70px;
    }
}

 /* for demo purposes (fixed top navbar placement in the fiddle. Ok to remove */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}

HTML


     <div class="span3">
       <div class="well sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-fixed">
          <img src="images/image.png">
       </div><!--/.well -->
     </div><!--/span-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try putting it in the 'nav-header' like this?

```
<div class="well sidebar-nav sidebar-nav-fixed">
         <ul class="nav nav-list">
           <li class="nav-header"><img src="images/image.png"></li>
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
           ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion and the image doesn't show up. As a matter of fact the rest of the sidebar links only show up on the mobile view.

Comment: Actually it did work.  I was working from a different version when I tried your fix.  Thanks!!